# Simply declaring a function signature from an external DLL does not give a runtime exception if the DLL or function doesn't exist, right?

Tags: c#, winapi, exception, dll, interop

For example, if I'm declaring:

```
internal static class WinAPI
{
    [DllImport("DwmApi.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
    internal static extern bool DwmIsCompositionEnabled();
}
```

but I'm not calling the *DwmIsCompositionEnabled* function in my project, I hope this will not raise an exception when running the program on systems where *DwmApi.dll* does not exist (or the function does not exist in that DLL). (Real case: *DwmApi.dll* requires Windows Vista, so it doesn't exist on Windows XP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only be a problem if and when the API is called.

You could consider a thin C# wrapper on the P/Invoke to facilitate handling the error, if you call this from multiple places.

Comment: Can you explain what "a thin C# wrapper on the P/Invoke" means or give me an example?

Comment: The idea is that if you P/Invoke the native API in multiple places, put this into a C# Adapter class that makes the P/Invoke and handles exceptions nicely.  This is instead of doing this all over the place, every time you P/Invoke.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't call it or don't use NGEN for deployment (ie: if you always rely on .NET Jit), you're fine.